# Override a UseControl's library

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to develope a WPF User Control Library that uses a Class Library with a member function that can be over-ridden .  I’m using C# 4.0 and VS 2010.

My test class library looks like:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace MyLibrary {
  public class Foo {
    virtual public void Bar() {
      Debug.WriteLine(" Hi from MyLibrary, class Foo, method Bar.");
    }
  }
}
```

My WPF User Control looks like:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using MyLibrary;
namespace MyUserControl {
  public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {
    public UserControl1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      Debug.WriteLine("MyUserControl: ");
      var foo = new Foo();
      foo.Bar();
    }
  }
}
```

I have built a WPF Application called ProgramA, and it looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
namespace ProgramA {
  public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

When debugging ProgramA, you will see:

```
MyUserControl: 
Hi from MyLibrary, class Foo, method Bar.
```

in the debug Output window.  So far, so good.

I have also built ProgramB to try to override the Bar method of MyLibrary.
ProgramB looks like:

```
using System.Windows;
namespace ProgramB {
  public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

The XML for both ProgramA and ProgramB contains a reference to MyUserControl:

```
<Window x:Class="ProgramB.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyUserControl;assembly=MyUserControl">
    <Grid>
    <my:UserControl1 Name="userControl11"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have added a Class to ProgramB's project called NewFoo.cs, and it looks like:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using MyLibrary;
namespace ProgramB {
  class NewFoo : MyLibrary.Foo{
    override public void Bar() {
      Debug.WriteLine(" Hi from ProgramB Foo, method Bar.");
    }
  }
}
```

ProgramB compiles and runs, but the output is:

```
MyUserControl: 
Hi from library Foo, method Bar.
```

The override did not work.

Here is the problem.  The Namespace for ProgramB’s Foo method is ProgramB, and hence it does not override the Bar method of MyLibrary.

Is there a way ProgramB can override the Bar method used by MyUserControl?

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
Charles

Comment: Maybe the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Its because `UserControl1` doesnt know about `NewFoo` and only instantiates `Foo`.  It has nothing to do with namespaces.

The override will work, as long as you provide the correct instance.

You should expose a property in `UserControl1` where you can set what `foo` to use.

Comment: I cannot do this in the real world application because NewFoo uses additional methods that are not loaded by ProgramA.

Comment: If your requirement is that `UserControl1` calls `Bar` method on a variable of type `Foo` that executes code in `NewFoo.Bar`, then some code, somewhere in `ProgramB`, must create an instance of NewFoo and give the reference to `UserControl1`.

Comment: Sorry, this does not make any sense to me.

Comment: I edited my original answer with some code. Let's identifiy the specific concept that needs more detailed explanation.